# UK Google Maps with check box options

Tags: google-maps

I just want UK google map with checkbox option. And check box have option like

```
Primary Schools 
Secondary Schools
Colleges 
Universities 
Transport
```

when any user click on these option then it activated, So my basic question is that, Is google provide any API for this purpose or i have to point out every single location because pointing out every single loaction is very time consuming. The example of this kind of map is [here](http://www.zoopla.co.uk/for-sale/details/28792741?search_identifier=2b00fb67c13a950426850d10627f53b0), go to map & nearby. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google does provide an API for this

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

The API does allow you to add parameters, for example

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml?location=37.77264,-122.409915&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&key=yourApiKey

Which will return a list of markers you can use to populate your map

Comment: It is not what i want, in this i have to give parameters. See my example how the are using map. I just need that kind of map. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks but i slove the problem.